# Viewing fixed header on mobile device

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi my website has a fixed horizontal nav bar and I'm having problems scrolling it on a mobile device when I zoom in. I did research and the only way to fix this issue is to use javascript.

I found a jquery solution (below) to this but I'm having difficulty turning it into an angular directive.  Any help?  Thanks

jquery that I'm trying to turn into an angular directive

```
if ($(window).width() < 990) {
$('#copyright').css({ 'left': (20 - $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px' });
$('#click-to-call, #erving').css({ 'right': (20 + $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px'});
 }
 $(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 990) {
$('#copyright').css({ 'left': (20 - $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px' });
$('#click-to-call, #erving').css({ 'right': (20 + $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px'});
}
else {
$('#copyright').css({ 'left': '20px' });
$('#click-to-call, #erving').css({ 'right': '20px' });
}
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.directive('fixedBar', function ($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      $win = angular.element($window);
      // Assuming these elements are static
      $lefties = element.find('#copyright');
      $righties = element.find('#click-to-call, #erving');

      function updateBar() {
        if ($win.width() < 990) {
          $lefties.css({ 'left': (20 - $win.scrollLeft()) + 'px' });
          $righties.css({ 'right': (20 + $win.scrollLeft()) + 'px'});
        } else {
          $lefties.css({ 'left': '20px' });
          $righties.css({ 'right': '20px' });
        }
      }

      $win.on('scroll', updateBar);

      updateBar();
    }
  }
}
```

would allow you to do this:

```
<nav fixed-bar>
  <div id="copyright"></div>
  <div id="click-to-call"></div>
  <div id="erving"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I put an alert('test') right under   function updateBar(),then I minimize the size of my browser, then I start scrolling.  However it doesn't run?  Shouldn't   $win.on('scroll', updateBar) run when I do this?

Comment: Yes, that should happen. Did it work for you eventually? As the green tick suggests that it solved your problem.

Comment: Actually no it didn't